Where is the term Paramahamsa Samhita with reference to srimad Bhagavatam used?
Is it to be only read by Paramahamsas?
Kindly quote where it is mentioned as Paramahamsa Samhita.

The colophons of Bhagavadgita also refers itself as a Paramahamsa samhita.
